# How to set the fixed volume for Alarms and clock independently of the general audio volume of PC?

Tags: alarm-clock

I mean how to make the volume of Alarms & clock
unresponsive to the changes of the general audio volume level?

So that I can rise or decrease the sound volume at will, without changing the alarm one.

Comment: Computer alarm clock will adjust sound volume automatically before playing the tune regardless of your PC's current settings. Increasing volume alarms will start by playing quiet music, raising the volume slowly if you won't wake up. (i want it to be like this as close as it can)

Comment: Do not add information in comments. Use the EDIT button to add information to the original question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Volume icon in the taskbar and go to Volume Mixer. You can set volume separately for System sounds and your running apps.

Note: This will change the volume of all system sounds like alert beeps along with the alarm sound. You could consider installing a separate timer app on your PC and using the Volume Mixer to set its volume separately.

Comment: They've updated it so that now it's for each individual app. If you open Volume Mixer in Windows Settings and play a sound from the Clock app, it should show up in the Apps list, and then you can adjust the volume.